# Is there a way to check if a symbol is quoted?

Tags: elisp

I'm trying to create a macro on Emacs Lisp and I'm struggling to see if a user may  pass a symbol quoted or not quoted.

Actually I need something like `quote-only-if-is-not-quoted` macro. Is there anything like that? I didn't found nothing about that on any Lisp dialect. Macro example:

```
(quote-only-if-is-not-quoted 'q) => (quote q)
(quote-only-if-is-not-quoted q) => (quote q)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The notion of “whether or not a symbol is quoted” is pretty meaningless because “quotedness” is not a concept. `quote`, when evaluated as a special form, disables evaluation of a datum. It doesn’t have any other special meaning, and, to an elisp macro, a “quoted” symbol is just a list containing two symbols where the first one is `quote`. Without more context, it’s extremely confusing to me what problem you’re trying to solve.

Comment: Right, thanks for the answer. I'm trying making that [macro](https://gist.github.com/ryukinix/f8b2231d1f2e3e8b95e4bb3312be5370) work in two ways: (when-system linux ...) and (when-system 'linux ...). In another words, I would wish that the first argument can be quoted only when is not passed as a quoted symbol. But in the way you did answer, now I think this is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macro arguments are *unevaluated*, so yes, you can check to see whether an argument is quoted and, if not, quote it. Something like this?

```el
(defmacro quote-only-if-is-not-quoted (arg)
  (if (and (consp arg)
           (eq (car arg) 'quote))
      arg
    `(quote ,arg)))
```

Comment: Exactly that! Thank you!